# How to distinguish between snap and normal application in "Activities"

Tags: gnome, snap, gnome-shell, activities-overview

If I have, say, Firefox installed both as a normal package and as a snap, they will appear in the *Activities* application listing and also two items will be returned by a search for "Firefox". Both show the same name and icon. How do I know which one to choose?

I know I can easily do it from the command line. But I would like to know what is the intended way from the Ubuntu GUI. Or, if that is a not yet implemented feature, if there is a GUI approach to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may create two new custom `.desktop` launchers for each in `~/.local/share/applications/`.

First create a file called `firefox.desktop` (for the default version) in `~/.local/share/applications/`. Open it with a text editor and put the following lines and save the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=default Firefox browser
Terminal=false
Name=Firefox (default)
Exec=firefox %u
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon/for/default/firefox
NoDisplay=false
```

Put the full path to the image (png or svg are preferable) you want to use as default Firefox's icon in place of `/path/to/icon/for/default/firefox` or simply put `Icon=firefox` if you want the default Firefox icon as per your icon theme.

Alternatively, copy the `firefox.desktop` file from `/usr/share/applications/` to `~/.local/share/applications/` and make the changes to `Name=` and `Icon=` fields as you wish.

Similarly, create another `.desktop` file, say `firefox-snap.desktop` (for the snap version) in `~/.local/share/applications/`.  Open it with a text editor and put the following lines and save the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=snappy Firefox browser
Terminal=false
Name=Firefox (snap)
Exec=/snap/bin/firefox
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/icon/for/snap/firefox
NoDisplay=false
```

Like before put the path to image file you want to use as the icon of snappy Firefox.

Now in Activities overview you'll see two Firefox launchers titled "*Firefox (default)*" and "*Firefox (snap)*". They will also have different icons if you have used different icons in their associated `.desktop` files.

**P.S.** You may use a GUI application like `alacarte` (aka "Main Menu") to create the launchers instead of manually creating and editing the `.desktop` files.