# How to add firejail to Ubuntu dock?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-dock

I have added firejail to the exec line by doing

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

The exec line now looks like this

```
Exec=firejail firefox %u
```

When I open FF by clicking on Activities then FF it opens with firejail sandbox

but if I add FF to favorites then launch it, it opens without firejail.

Any ideas ?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME).

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1031911/edit) to include the edited `Exec=` line

Comment: This is a very similar question, and the answer should work for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019125/how-to-distinguish-between-snap-and-normal-application-in-activities

Comment: There already exists a .desktop entry for Firefox with firejail added. Problem is when launched from favorites it opens  without firejail sandbox.

Comment: probably because you edited the system one, not the one in your home directory

Comment: @ Sebastian Stark Which file in my home directory should I modify ? and how ?

Comment: I just realized that favorites are handled differently, sorry for the wrong advice.

Comment: to me it looks like a bug in the ubuntu dock

Comment: @SebastianStark Has anyone reported the bug ? Did you find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Pinning to favorites seems to be problematic for custom desktop launchers sometimes. You can manually add a launcher to your favorites by doing this:

Create a custom launcher with a new name, e. g. `$HOME/.local/share/applications/jailfox.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=jailfox
Exec=firejail firefox
Icon=firefox
Type=Application
```

Add it to the favorites manually, not by dragging and dropping, using `dconf-editor`:

[image: dconf-editor favorites]

The icon should appear when you click "apply".

This method has a downside: When you start firefox by clicking on the custom icon, a second firefox icon will appear for the running instance.

You can check that firefox is indeed running inside firejail like this:

```
> firejail --list
1556:seb:firejail firefox 
1219:seb:firejail --list
```